# Irregular tile size in matplotlib hexbin

Tags: matplotlib, size, tile

When making a hexbin plot in matplotlib, I find that alternating rows of hexagon tiles have different sizes, sometimes significantly so. This demonstration code shows the effect:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm as cm
from matplotlib import mlab as ml
import numpy as np

n = 1e5
x = y = np.linspace(-5, 5, 100)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z1 = ml.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 2, 2, 0, 0)
Z2 = ml.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 4, 1, 1, 1)
ZD = Z2 - Z1
x = X.ravel()
y = Y.ravel()
z = ZD.ravel()
plt.subplot(111)

plt.hexbin(x, y, C=z, gridsize=30, cmap=cm.jet, bins=None)
plt.axis([x.min(), x.max(), y.min(), y.max()])

cb = plt.colorbar()
cb.set_label('mean value')
plt.show()
```

In [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVwuE.png), with a gridsize of 30, you can see that alternate rows are squished a bit vertically:

The effect is not very significant, but in [this magnified view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hh0r0.png) of the same hexbin plot but with a gridsize of 80, the small rows are nearly half the size of the large rows. (The generated sample data starts to mis-align with the grid, too, but that's an unimportant artifact.)

The hexbin documentation reads:

> gridsize: [ 100 | integer ]
>
> The number of hexagons in the x-direction, default is 100. The corresponding number of hexagons in the y-direction is chosen such that the hexagons are approximately regular. Alternatively, gridsize can be a tuple with two elements specifying the number of hexagons in the x-direction and the y-direction.

It only guarantees that the hexagons be "approximately" regular, but it seems that, especially in cases like the 80-gridsize image above, the hexagons could be made a lot closer to regular by reducing the number of rows so small rows could be enlarged and made more regular. Or, the normal-sized rows could be shrunk vertically while the small ones are enlarged vertically, keeping all rows the same height, even if the tiles aren't regularly-shaped.

What is the cause of this irregularity, and can it be avoided?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After some more experimentation, I think I've found the cause. The documentation for hexbin also mentions:

> linewidths: [ None | scalar ]
>
> If None, defaults to rc lines.linewidth.
> Note that this is a tuple, and if you set the linewidths argument you
> must set it as a sequence of floats, as required by
> RegularPolyCollection.
>
> Other keyword arguments controlling the
> Collection properties:
>
> edgecolors: [ None | 'none' | mpl color | color sequence ]
>
> **If 'none',
> draws the edges in the same color as the fill color. This is the
> default, as it avoids unsightly unpainted pixels between the hexagons.**
>
> If None, draws the outlines in the default color.
>
> If a matplotlib color arg or sequence of rgba tuples, draws the
> outlines in the specified color.

By setting linewidths to (0,), I exposed the unsightly unpainted pixels, but my hexagons were all the same size. It seems that some rows of hexagons were in a higher layer and being drawn with overly-large borders protruding over neighboring rows. A linewidths value of (1,) gives the uneven results I was seeing before, so it may be the default. A linewidths between 0 and 1 (I'm using 0.25) covers the unpainted pixels without causing much overlap, producing a much nicer plot. However, this only happens when saving the image via savefig() at a higher DPI than default (I'm using dpi=300). Calling show() or saving with the default DPI produces plots with the unpainted pixels uncovered. So while effective, this workaround is somewhat limited.